# Django FieldError on poly__within

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I cannot further find the cause why Django presents an error at the line where I call `poly__within` to query [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/) in PostGIS.

My model doesn't have a `poly` yet the error below says its a FieldError. I do not know where or why its looking for a field for `poly`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/network/views.py", line 71, in view_routes
    routes = Route.objects.filter(poly__within= geom[0])
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 784, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 802, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1276, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1154, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1034, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1352, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'poly' into field. Choices are: agency, agency_id, created_at, distance, duration, ogc_fid, route_color, route_desc, route_id, route_long, route_name, route_tcolor, route_type, route_url, shape_id, updated_at, wkb_geometry
```

This is how it looks like in my views.py

```
json_feature = json.loads(request.POST['geo_obj'])
geom = make_geometry_from_feature(json_feature)
routes = Route.objects.filter(poly__within= geom[0])
```

Comment: Can you add your `models.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django filter syntax is that the first part of your keyword argument, before the `__` is the field name. `Route.objects.filter(poly__within=geom[0])` filters for a Route object where the `poly` field is within the given geometry.

You haven't shared your `Route` model, but I assume it has a geometry field on it. If so, you should replace `poly` here with the name of your geometry field. e.g. if your model looks like this

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Route(models.Model):
    shape = models.MultiPolygonField()
```

then your filter should be `Route.objects.filter(shape__within=geom[0])`.

Comment: AH! My bad! I thought from the django docs that `poly__within` is as is. Thank you for pointing this out!